# Conditional expectation of the product of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}$. The tower property of conditional expectation says that $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XY | \mathcal{G}]]$. Suppose that we do not impose any further assumptions on independence and measurability of $X$ and $Y$, I want to ask is it true that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[Y | \mathcal{G}]],
\end{equation}

and how can one prove it if it is true. Any ideas?

Comment: It is true if $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable. The rule is that ''you can take out everything which is measurable''. Try to prove this using the definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: @Lucien Yes, This is ture if $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. But I want to know the general case if we do not have such an assumption.

Comment: This was asked very recently on the site. The answer is: No (try X=Y independent of G).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $\mathcal G:=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Then $\mathbb E[Y\mid\mathcal G]=\mathbb EY$ so that: $$\mathbb E[X\mathbb E[Y\mid\mathcal G]]=\mathbb E[X\mathbb EY]=\mathbb EX\mathbb EY$$

This does not necessarily equal $\mathbb EXY$.